# Session.QueryOver: What does error : variable 'rg' of type ReportingGroup referenced from scope , but it is not defined" mean?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

This is the query:

```
 var reportingGroupYears = _session.QueryOver<ReportingGroup>()
                            .Where(x => x.Number == request.ReportingGroupNumber)
                            .Select(rg=> rg.Year.ToString())
                            .List<string>();
```

I don't understand what is wrong with it. Defining 'rg' as string is not allowed either, as it give message that it would give rg a different meaning than the one defined in parent scope.

Comment: Why do you need to cast year to string?

Comment: Can see the definition of ReportingGroup and request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `Select` clause is an issue for NHibernate. It expects the property *(during the expression tree parsing)* to be converted into SELECT statement. But there is a method call: `.ToString()`.

One way how to solve it, could be explicit `Projection` like this (see doc QueryOver [16.6. Projections](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-projections))

```
var reportingGroupYears = session
    .QueryOver<ReportingGroup>()
    .Where(x => x.Number == request.ReportingGroupNumber)
    .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("Year"))
        ))
        .List<string>();
```